# My Code is working in Blogger but not in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

Sir, My code is working properly in blogger but it is not working in wordpress. I'm a beginner so please help to resolve the issue. Please make some necessary changes to make it functional.

```
<style>
.button {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0066ff, #00a1ff, #00c6eb, #00e087, #a8eb12);
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: small;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 3px;
}
.techly360{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0066ff, #00a1ff, #00c6eb, #00e087, #a8eb12);
    color: white;
}
</style>

<div style="text-align: center;">
<a href="#" id="download" class="button">Download File</a>

<button id="btn" class="techly360">Click to Download</button>

<script>
var downloadButton = document.getElementById("download");
var counter = 10;
var newElement = document.createElement("p");
newElement.innerHTML = "10 sec";
var id;

downloadButton.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, downloadButton);

function startDownload() {
    this.style.display = 'none';
    id = setInterval(function () {
        counter--;
        if (counter < 0) {
            newElement.parentNode.replaceChild(downloadButton, newElement);
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            newElement.innerHTML = +counter.toString() + " second.";
        }
    }, 1000);
};

var clickbtn = document.getElementById("btn");
clickbtn.onclick = startDownload;
</script>
```

Comment: where you have used this code?

Comment: Actually I'm using this code in a post. I want to show a download button. When user clicks on that button then countdown starts and user have to wait for some time then an another button will show by which user can download the file.

Comment: It will not work like the way you are using. Put that code in functions.php using wp_header hook or create a js file and call that in header using wp enqueue script hook.

Comment: Open HTML Content of WP Post and write this code there. You will get your desired functionality then

Answer (score 0):

```js
var downloadButton = document.getElementById("download");
var counter = 10;
var newElement = document.createElement("p");
newElement.innerHTML = "10 sec";
var id;

downloadButton.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, downloadButton);

function startDownload() {
    this.style.display = 'none';
    id = setInterval(function () {
        counter--;
        if (counter < 0) {
            newElement.parentNode.replaceChild(downloadButton, newElement);
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            newElement.innerHTML = +counter.toString() + " second.";
        }
    }, 1000);
};

var clickbtn = document.getElementById("btn");
clickbtn.onclick = startDownload;
```

```css
.button {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0066ff, #00a1ff, #00c6eb, #00e087, #a8eb12);
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: small;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 3px;
}
.techly360{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0066ff, #00a1ff, #00c6eb, #00e087, #a8eb12);
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
<a href="#" id="download" class="button">Download File</a>
<button id="btn" class="techly360">Click to Download</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

The structure of work in WordPress is different. if you use this code as a html file it's work true. like this:
https://file.io/4a0F1OL14avi

but in wordpress you need to seperate codes. (like as image)
1-copy html code in post content
2-copy style and script in header.php (in root of the theme) before

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7USw.jpg)

Comment: The first link is not working, the page was deleted. Could you not just put code examples in the question and be more specific?